# Self-SIgned SSL for internal network security

Tags: java, rest, https, jetty

We want to use self signed certificated for our internal services, really just so that everything is sent over the network encrypted.

The problem I have is with the securing of self-signed certificate. All the Jetty instances use the same keystore, so in theory the certificate is loaded... In fact from debug logging I have

> found key for : staging-linweb01 chain [0] = [ [   Version: V3
>   Subject: CN=staging-linweb01, OU=Software Development,
>   O=someplace.com, L=Somewhere, ST=Somewhere, C=ZA   Signature
>   Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
>
> Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits   modulus:
>   22594784587200309690632891312059150804687308973808921580591096263533343618426439789480037039157188264460595867528454151674753231237005959217826687232762068209631355533459054189119044758749514636616657620359265671087314976126553620526394561605421420641752060671870955789723877860923654282485572976527919222352468625611759566014112451145405478791894271337944800006309556312833441960744532218846058383652408555521199029813985649443614702157985283090052710238306045838371894973518144370565750444076220567222222129612928685843812450625948488824030966348721650049514411578506927346702477393053734393778851627929324041999837
>   public exponent: 65537   Validity: [From: Thu Dec 10 08:41:14 UTC
>   2015,
>                  To: Wed Mar 09 08:41:14 UTC 2016]   Issuer: CN=staging-linweb01, OU=Software Development, O=someplace.com,
>   L=Somewhere, ST=Somewhere, C=ZA   SerialNumber: [    3485f931]
>
> Certificate Extensions: 2 [1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
>   SubjectAlternativeName [   IPAddress: 130.211.63.142   DNSName:
>   staging-linweb01 ]
>
> [2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false SubjectKeyIdentifier [
>   KeyIdentifier [ 0000: B9 29 B3 C0 04 A3 BD 07   F9 AC E2 30 8A DB 25
>   D1  .).........0..%. 0010: 80 0C F6 24
>   ...$ ] ]
>
> ]   Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]   Signature: 0000: 6C FD C0 AD 60 78 CB
>   43   DA F2 EF AD 42 D8 A1 05  l...`x.C....B... 0010: 72 AD 0E 6B 75 50
>   2D 85   6E 81 A7 6D 5D 50 ED CA  r..kuP-.n..m]P.. 0020: ED 75 E2 BB 18
>   A8 59 21   BA 10 DF 7A E0 42 5E 2C  .u....Y!...z.B^, 0030: F3 DD 05 96
>   C1 F8 E5 18   5B A4 F2 15 FC 04 67 7B  ........[.....g. 0040: C4 6C 67
>   F5 F4 07 E8 57   FC 88 77 C6 92 3C B8 1E  .lg....W..w..<.. 0050: A2 7E
>   AE D5 0D 1B F2 78   28 17 74 6C E0 FD D4 09  .......x(.tl.... 0060: B8
>   2D AF E2 A2 7B 57 0D   E2 B6 F4 CF 76 57 E9 A9  .-....W.....vW.. 0070:
>   84 8E 38 1B A2 42 8F 20   C4 BC E6 28 61 96 9A 4B  ..8..B. ...(a..K
>   0080: D3 3D 69 E2 24 51 F4 96   02 DD 54 25 5A 8C 7C 15 
>   .=i.$Q....T%Z... 0090: 7A 26 E4 14 6A 2A DF EE   DE EF 1E F1 71 D0 CE
>   FA  z&..j*......q... 00A0: 2A 28 99 33 00 B3 50 18   BC FF E5 23 ED 57
>   B4 A0  *(.3..P....#.W.. 00B0: AB F7 B3 5B E6 33 52 52   86 8C AD DC A6
>   86 FF A5  ...[.3RR........ 00C0: 3F 02 D1 9F 54 2F A3 5B   72 01 CE 00
>   C3 FA 63 8E  ?...T/.[r.....c. 00D0: DE F0 E1 3D CA 76 67 68   85 7B 38
>   80 35 A8 A7 30  ...=.vgh..8.5..0 00E0: 4B 72 2C DB AA 03 A6 E0   3B 75
>   AE 87 DF 1F 9C BA  Kr,.....;u...... 00F0: 4C 51 91 8D 28 DD 79 C4   8C
>   A1 D3 A5 51 37 D1 9A  LQ..(.y.....Q7..
>
> ]
>   *** adding as trusted cert:   Subject: CN=staging-linweb01, OU=Software Development, O=someplace.com, L=Somewhere, ST=Somewhere
>   , C=ZA   Issuer:  CN=staging-linweb01, OU=Software Development,
>   O=someplace.com, L=Somewhere, ST=Somewhere, C=ZA   Algorithm:
>   RSA; Serial number: 0x3485f931   Valid from Thu Dec 10 08:41:14 UTC
>   2015 until Wed Mar 09 08:41:14 UTC 2016
>
> trigger seeding of SecureRandom done seeding SecureRandom

But when trying to make a call, even if it is from the server to itself, I get this exception.

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   POST request for
>   "https://staging-linweb01/security/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials":sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
>   PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I've also tried adding the keystore with `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore` but still get this problem.

How do I go about configuring Jetty and / or my services to not cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add your certificate to java key store?
Path should be: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.x.0/jre/lib/security

Answer (score 0):

you need to export this certificate from your keystore and add it to the truststore. If not explicitly specified I think the default truststore from the jvm is used. It should be in "jre/lib/security/cacerts" and the password is changeit unless you changed it.

To import your cert simply use the following command:

`keytool -keystore jre/lib/security/cacerts -importcert -alias myCert -file myCert.cert -storepass changeit -noprompt`

Or simply configure jetty with the keystore as a truststore.
For a full configuration guide see: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL